# Что означает такое смещение -148(%rbp)

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc

Имеется такой цикл на Си:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = B[i] * C[i];
    }
```

Судя по всему его ассемблерный аналог - это вот это 
Можете объяснить, как он работает ?

```
.L5:
    movl    -148(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movl    -96(%rbp,%rax,4), %edx
    movl    -148(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movl    -48(%rbp,%rax,4), %eax
    imull   %eax, %edx
    movl    -148(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movl    %edx, -144(%rbp,%rax,4)
    addl    $1, -148(%rbp)
.L4:
    cmpl    $9, -148(%rbp)
    jle .L5
```

Пытаюсь понять эти смещения по аналогии с  -16(%rcx) , который на 16 байтов ниже адреса (%rcx) , это происходит, потому что стек сверху вниз растет ?

Откуда вообще такие числа берутся(-148,-96)

UPD -144(%rbp,%rax,4) == -144+%rbp+%rax*4

Осталось только понять, откуда такие смещения взялись

Comment: rbp обычно содержит точку стека на момент входа в процедуру. все локальные переменные размещаются в стеке. так как стек растет вниз то все переменные находятся в rbp минус что нибудь. судя по всему вы в своей функции объявили переменных на 148 байт. При размещении переменных в памяти компилятор посчитал где какая находится и использует эти смещения далее в тексте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.L5:
    movl    -148(%rbp), %eax        ; Загрузка в eax значения переменной цикла i (37-е двойное слово в стеке)
    cltq
    movl    -96(%rbp,%rax,4), %edx  ; Загрузка в edx значения B[i]
    movl    -148(%rbp), %eax        ; Загрузка переменной цикла i
    cltq
    movl    -48(%rbp,%rax,4), %eax  ; Загрузка в eax значения C[i]
    imull   %eax, %edx              ; Умножение B[i] * C[i]
    movl    -148(%rbp), %eax        ; Загрузка переменной цикла i
    cltq
    movl    %edx, -144(%rbp,%rax,4) ; Сохранение результата умножения в A[i]
    addl    $1, -148(%rbp)          ; Инкремент переменной цикла i
.L4:
    cmpl    $9, -148(%rbp)          ; Проверка условия цикла
    jle .L5                         ; Итерация
```

Компилятор выделяет для всех локальных переменных место в стеке и расставляет соответствующие им смещения в сгенерированном коде.